# Coursera's Google data analytics Module 3 joins section syntax error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I encounter this error while trying to request SQL to JOIN values in two tables Coursera's Google Data Analytics course in Module 3 (Understanding JOINS).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU2z0.png)

What can I do to correctly get the syntax and run the query?

I followed the instructor in entering the syntax, but no luck.

Due to the fact that my dataset and table names are a bit different I entered the query accordingly.

I am expecting the query to return records with employee names and department IDs for employees with matching IDs.

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    EDE.name AS employee_name, 
    EDE.role AS employee_role,
    EDD.name AS department_name
FROM  
    ' employee_data.employees ' AS EDE
INNER JOIN
    ' employee_data.departments ' AS EDD
ON EDE.department_id = EDD.department_id
```

BigQuery gets confused with the names so I assign some aliases to help it recognize them.